# Create documents in different firestore collections, with same reference ID

Tags: firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My question is actually twofold, so I m not sure I should ask both in one post or create another post. Anyway, here it is:

I am creating users in firestore database. I do not want to put all details in a single document because it will be requested a lot, and all details will be retrieved, even if not needed. So I decided to create a collection `members_full` with all details of users I may not need often, and another collection called `members_header` to keep the few most important details. On creation of a new user, I want reference ID in both collections to be the same for a specific user.

```
- members_full -+
                |
                + --- abnGMbre --- +
                                   |
                                   + --- mother : 'His mom'
                                   + --- Father:  'daddy'

- members_header+
                |   
                + ---- abnGMbre -- +
                                   |
                                   + ---- fullname: 'john Doe'
                                   + ---- pictURL: 'path to his profile pic'
```

I want something looking like the above.
So this is what I did in the cloud function:

```
/** Create / Update a member
 * ------------------------- */
exports.updateMember = functions.https.onCall( (data, context) =>{
  // root member and secretaries are allowed to update members
  const authParams:any = {
    uid:      context.auth.uid,
    email:    context.auth.token.email,
  };
  // Check if user is allowed to perform operation
  return checkPermission(authParams, ['root', 'secretary']).then(res => {
    if(res==false){
      return { // Permission denied
        status: STATUS.permission_denied,
      }
    }
    // set object to add/ update
    const member:any = data;
    // Check if uid of member object is present (true:update, false: create)
    var fullRef : admin.firestore.DocumentReference;
    var headRef : admin.firestore.DocumentReference;
    var countRef: admin.firestore.DocumentReference;
    var createNewMember  = false;
    if(member.uid!==undefined && member.uid!==null){ // update
      fullRef  = fsDB.collection('members_full').doc(member.uid);
      headRef  = fsDB.collection('members_header').doc(member.uid);
    } else {
      fullRef  = fsDB.collection('members_full').doc();
      headRef  = fsDB.collection('members_header').doc(fullRef.id);
      countRef = fsDB.collection('counters').doc('members');
      createNewMember  = true;
    }

    return fsDB.runTransaction(t => {
      return t.get(fullRef).then(doc => {
        // Update full details
        t.set(fullRef, {
          surname     : member.surname     ,
          firstName   : member.firstName   ,
          birthDate   : member.birthDate   ,
          birthPlace  : member.birthPlace  ,
          email       : member.email       ,
          phone       : member.phone       ,
          occupation  : member.occupation  ,
          father      : member.father      ,
          mother      : member.mother      ,
          spouse      : member.spouse      ,
          children    : member.children    ,
          addressHome : member.addressHome ,
          addressLocal: member.addressLocal,
          contactHome : member.contactHome ,
          contactLocal: member.contactLocal,
          comment     : member.comment     ,
          regDate     : member.regDate     ,
        });
        // Update header details
        t.set(headRef, {
          fullName    : member.fullName    ,
          gender      : member.gender      ,
          active      : member.active      ,
          picURL      : member.picURL      ,
        });
        // Increment number of members
        if(createNewMember ){
          t.update(countRef, {count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
        }

      }).then(() => {
        return { status : STATUS.ok  }
      }).catch(err => {
        return {
          status: STATUS.fail,
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        }
      });
    }).then(() => {
      return { status : STATUS.ok  }
    }).catch(error =>{
      return {
        status: STATUS.fail,
        message: error.message,
        debug:  'run transaction err',
        error: error
      }
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    return {
      status:   STATUS.fail,
      message:  err.message,
      debug:  'check permission err',
      error:    err
    }
  });
});


/** Check if authenticated user's roles are among the ones allowed 
 * --------------------------------------------------------------- */
function checkPermission(authParams:any, allowedRoles:any[]):Promise<boolean>{
  // Check if authenticated user as any of the roles in array 'allowedRoles'
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // If one of allowed roles is root, check against global variables
    if(allowedRoles.indexOf('root')>=0 && 
        ( root_auth.email.localeCompare(authParams.email)==0 || 
          root_auth.uid.localeCompare(authParams.uid)==0)){
      resolve(true);
    }
    // Get autID
    const uid = authParams.uid;
    // Get corresponding user in collection roles
    admin.firestore().collection('userRoles').doc(uid).get().then(snap => {
      // Get roles of user and compare against all roles in array 'allowedRoles'
      const memRoles  = snap.data().roles;
      var   found     = false;
      var   zz        = memRoles.length;
      for(let z=0; z<zz; z++){
        if(allowedRoles.indexOf(memRoles[z])){
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      resolve(found);
    }).catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

When I call this cloud function, it only writes in document `members_full`, and increment number of members. It does not create entry in `members_header`.
My first question: where did I go wrong? the way I' m getting ID from the first document to create second document, isn't it valid?

The second question, will it be better to create subcollections rather than having 2 collections? if yes, how to do I do that in a transaction?

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chain the method calls in the Transaction. It is not extremely clear in the documentation, but if you look at the reference document for a Transaction (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Transaction) you will see that the `update()` and `set()` methods return a Transaction, which is 
the "Transaction instance. [and is] **used for chaining method calls**".

So you should adapt your code along these lines:

```
        return fsDB.runTransaction(t => {
            return t.get(fullRef)
            .then(doc => {
                t.set(fullRef, {
                     surname     : member.surname     ,
                     firstName   : member.firstName  
                     //....   
                })
                .set(headRef, {
                     //....
                     gender      : member.gender   
                     //....
                })
                .update(countRef, {count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
            });
        });
```

---

You also need to correctly chain all the different promises, as follows:

```
return checkPermission(authParams, ['root', 'secretary'])
.then(res => {
    //...
    return fsDB.runTransaction(t => {
      //.....
    });
.then(t => {
    return { status : STATUS.ok  }
})
.catch(error => {...})
```

---

**However,** you may use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) instead of a transaction, since it appears that you don't use the document returned by `t.get(fullRef)` in the transaction.

---

For your second question, IMHO there is no reason to use sub-collections instead of two (root) collections.

Comment: Hi! @renaud-tarnec. Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately, after trying both your proposed approaches, nothing works! nothing gets written or updated. I m still revieweing my code to see if I missed something when I was modifying it...

Comment: Can you modify your question to add the entire code of the Cloud Function (including the trigger part and not only the inner code).

Comment: I modified the question to include the full function

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer. Actually it appears that you should better use a batched write. (Also note that in the first version of my answer, the first approach for chaining the transaction write methods was wrong!)

Comment: Hi Thanks again. My code wasn't too bad actually, but missed few things. And yours is much better. Actually, after using your solution, it still wasn't working because by mistake I removed a field in the object that is sent to the function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PhoenixBlue Glad that I could help you! You may also upvote the answer if you think it was helpful! Thanks.